# Prevent react native component from re-rendering on every state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, components, state

I have a component witch should either show A or B based on whether the user is nearby a certain location. I created a custom hook for retrieving the value of the user being nearby.

My problem is that the hook keeps returning a new value `true`, even though the value of `isNearby` is not changing. Once it's been set to `true`, it should remain `true`. That's it.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useDistanceTo from './useDistanceTo';
import { Coordinates } from '../screens/backend/Distance';

const useIsNearby = (locationCoordinate) => {
  const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState<Coordinates>(null)
  const [isNearby, setIsNearby] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const distance = useDistanceTo(coordinate);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCoordinate(locationCoordinate);
  }, [locationCoordinate.latitude])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(distance)
    if (
      (distance || distance === 0) &&
      distance !== -1 &&
      distance < 50
    ) {
      setIsNearby(true);
    }
  }, [distance]);

  return isNearby;
};

export default useIsNearby;
```

```
export default function Component({ locationCoordinate }) {
  const isNearby = useIsNearby(locationCoordinate);

  const logA = () => {
    console.log('test');
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { isNearby ?
        logA()
      :
        <Text>Show B</Text>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

The console keeps outputting `test` whenever the distance changes. I'm pretty sure I have some fundamentals of react wrong. What am I missing / should I fix?

The log is actually an entering animation that keeps running again and again, which it shouldn't. I tried to simplify the actual issue and tried several ways to include useRef. All without success.

I'm looking for a solution in which the component is only updated when the value of isNearby actually changes, so logA() won't keep doing new outputs.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the react docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate), setState won't trigger a re-render if the value is the same as the previous value (determined by Object.is). In this case, true is a primitive and will not cause a re-render.

The fundamental of react which you may be missing is that for any of this to even get calculated, a render has to happen. Once you enter the function, you will always exit through the return statement, and logA will always get called (assuming isNearby was true at the start of the render).

Actually, since you also call setCoordinate, I would expect to see test logged *twice*, once on the render that detects the change, and once after calling setCoordinate. You also mentioned this is an animation, and I would guess that when the animation completes, something triggers a render, which would log test a third time, and apparently also restart the animation if this is how you're triggering it.

But remember that *any* location change would start the animation if this is your exact code, because logA is always called when isNearby is true, not just when it changes from false to true.

Under the hood, the code inside curly brackets is always called, it's just used to tell the jsx parser that this is Javascript instead of plain text. The JSX you listed above is actually converted to the following code, which as you can tell, is not contained inside any functions and will always run.

```
import { createElement as ce } from "react";
...
  return (
    ce(View, {style: styles.container},
       isNearby ?
        logA()
      :
      ce(Text, {}, "Show B")
    )
  )
```

I'm assuming that you understand that nothing in your Component code differentiates between different values of true returned by useIsNearby. I'm not sure why you think that it is returning different values of true, since your code will always fire logA no matter "which value of true" is being returned. Technically this isn't a thing with primitives in Javascript, so I'm not sure why you worded it that way, but there is nothing in your code which would differentiate that even if you were returning an object (which would be "truthy"). If useIsNearby returned a different object every time, or the same object, your component as written here would respond the same regardless.

**Edit:** In order to prevent logA from being called every single time, you should probably call useEffect and pass in the result of useIsNearby as a dependancy, as shown below. But since you obviously already understand `useEffect`, I'm guessing there's a reason you're doing it in the render call.

**Edit:** I don't even know if anyone does animationStarter that way, it's just a stab in the dark since I don't know how your animation works and I don't normally work with animations in my line of work.

```
  const isNearby = useIsNearby(locationCoordinate);

  const logA = () => {
    console.log('test');
    return null;
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    if(isNearby) {
      console.log("start your animation with Show A");
      logA(); 
    }
    return () => { 
      console.log("cancel animation and do something different"); 
    } 
  }, [isNearby]);

  const animationStarter = useMemo(() => {
    return isNearby ? { /* animation settings or who knows what */ } : null;
  }, [isNearby]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      { animationStarter ?
        <AnimatedText animated={animationStarter}>Show A</Text>
      :
        <Text>Show B</Text>
      }
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: Location is static for the screen that is shown to the user. The user location is dynamic, but that is abstracted away in the distance hook. So, distance is the value that is changing, and whenever distance changes, logA() is outputting 'test'.

If I understand correctly, the distance useEffect is going to be called every time distance changes, which will set IsNearby to true, which will make the custom hook return it to the component. Which will cause a re-render.

Is there a way to prevent this? Do I need a totally different approach?

(btw, 'test' is indeed logged twice at first)

Comment: In the component you included, the location coordinates are coming in as a prop, which means that every single time the location changes the component has to re-render to even be able to decide whether the user is nearby and so forth. Calling useIsNearby happens *during* the render.  Regardless of whether or not useIsNearby returns true, the code in the Component is being run, and if it returns true, logA is also called. A component is just a function and everything you see there get's executed just like a regular Javascript function.

Comment: You seem to be using a mental model where everything is an observable and you're piping data changes through. That isn't how React works, it just uses vanilla Javascript and manipulates primitives. The only thing being changed is the JSX syntax which basically just returns an object tree describing it. Nothing in your function gets transpiled into any other format beyond that.

Comment: See the edit I added. Why aren't you using useEffect to start the animation? Renders happen constantly and you can't easily restrict them from happening for a bunch of reasons. The best you can do is return as fast as physically possible by caching stuff in useMemo and delegating UI stuff to useEffect calls.

Comment: Since this is react native and you're having constant animations, is it possible that you need to cache something with useMemo that you're passing into the animated component, whatever that is? I don't work with animations, so I don't know how that normally works.